# Write multiple data in excel file having column name TestCol and TestCol1 in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java

I want to write multiple data in excel with column name like TestCol and TestCol1.
Same data store in excel, now want to read either TestCol or TestCol1.

Xls_reader reader = new Xls_reader();
        reader.Xls_Reader("C:uat\testdata\FreeCMSTestData.xlsx");

```
    reader.addSheet("TestData");
    reader.addColumn("TestData", "TestCol");
    reader.addColumn("TestData", "TestCol1");
    int n=3;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        reader.setCellData("TestData", "TestCol", i, str1);
        reader.setCellData("TestData", "TestCol1", i, part);


    }
```

Now, Data is not going in respective Column one below the other instead it get add to the adjacent.

public class Xls_reader {

```
public String path;
public FileInputStream fis = null;
public FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
private XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
private XSSFSheet sheet = null;
private XSSFRow row = null;
private XSSFCell cell = null;

public void Xls_Reader(String path) {

    this.path = path;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// returns the row count in a sheet

public int getRowCount(String sheetName) {
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if (index == -1)
        return 0;
    else {
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        int number = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        return number;
    }

}
// returns the data from a cell

public String getCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum) {
    try {
        if (rowNum <= 0)
            return "";

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int col_Num = -1;
        if (index == -1)
            return "";

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                col_Num = i;
        }
        if (col_Num == -1)
            return "";

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
        if (row == null)
            return "";
        cell = row.getCell(col_Num);

        if (cell == null)
            return "";
        // System.out.println(cell.getCellType());
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {

            String cellText = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                // format in form of M/D/YY
                double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                cellText = (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                cellText = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "/" + cellText;

                // System.out.println(cellText);

            }

            return cellText;
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
            return "";
        else
            return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return "row " + rowNum + " or column " + colName + " does not exist in xls";
    }
}

// returns the data from a cell
public String getCellData(String sheetName, int colNum, int rowNum) {
    try {
        if (rowNum <= 0)
            return "";

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);

        if (index == -1)
            return "";

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
        if (row == null)
            return "";
        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        if (cell == null)
            return "";

        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {

            String cellText = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                // format in form of M/D/YY
                double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                cellText = (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                cellText = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cellText;

                // System.out.println(cellText);

            }

            return cellText;
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
            return "";
        else
            return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return "row " + rowNum + " or column " + colNum + " does not exist  in xls";
    }
}

// returns true if data is set successfully else false
public boolean setCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String data) {
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if (rowNum <= 0)
            return false;

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum = -1;
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
                colNum = i;
        }
        if (colNum == -1)
            return false;

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum - 1);

        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);

        // cell style
        // CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
        // cs.setWrapText(true);
        // cell.setCellStyle(cs);
        cell.setCellValue(data);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// returns true if data is set successfully else false
public boolean setCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String data, String url) {
    // System.out.println("setCellData setCellData******************");
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if (rowNum <= 0)
            return false;

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum = -1;
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        // System.out.println("A");
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(colName))
                colNum = i;
        }

        if (colNum == -1)
            return false;
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); // ashish
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum - 1);

        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);

        cell.setCellValue(data);
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        // cell style for hyperlinks
        // by default hypelrinks are blue and underlined
        CellStyle hlink_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont hlink_font = workbook.createFont();
        hlink_font.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
        hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
        hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
        // hlink_style.setWrapText(true);

        XSSFHyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(XSSFHyperlink.LINK_FILE);
        link.setAddress(url);
        cell.setHyperlink(link);
        cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// returns true if sheet is created successfully else false
public boolean addSheet(String sheetname) {

    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try {
        workbook.createSheet(sheetname);
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// returns true if sheet is removed successfully else false if sheet does
// not exist
public boolean removeSheet(String sheetName) {
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if (index == -1)
        return false;

    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try {
        workbook.removeSheetAt(index);
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// returns true if column is created successfully
public boolean addColumn(String sheetName, String colName) {
    // System.out.println("**************addColumn*********************");

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(0);

        // cell = row.getCell();
        // if (cell == null)
        // System.out.println(row.getLastCellNum());
        if (row.getLastCellNum() == -1)
            cell = row.createCell(0);
        else
            cell = row.createCell(row.getLastCellNum());

        cell.setCellValue(colName);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

// removes a column and all the contents
public boolean removeColumn(String sheetName, int colNum) {
    try {
        if (!isSheetExist(sheetName))
            return false;
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.NO_FILL);

        for (int i = 0; i < getRowCount(sheetName); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if (row != null) {
                cell = row.getCell(colNum);
                if (cell != null) {
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                    row.removeCell(cell);
                }
            }
        }
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

// find whether sheets exists
public boolean isSheetExist(String sheetName) {
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if (index == -1) {
        index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName.toUpperCase());
        if (index == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    } else
        return true;
}

// returns number of columns in a sheet
public int getColumnCount(String sheetName) {
    // check if sheet exists
    if (!isSheetExist(sheetName))
        return -1;

    sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    row = sheet.getRow(0);

    if (row == null)
        return -1;

    return row.getLastCellNum();

}

// String sheetName, String testCaseName,String keyword ,String URL,String
// message
public boolean addHyperLink(String sheetName, String screenShotColName, String testCaseName, int index, String url,
        String message) {
    // System.out.println("ADDING addHyperLink******************");

    url = url.replace('\\', '/');
    if (!isSheetExist(sheetName))
        return false;

    sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

    for (int i = 2; i <= getRowCount(sheetName); i++) {
        if (getCellData(sheetName, 0, i).equalsIgnoreCase(testCaseName)) {
            // System.out.println("**caught "+(i+index));
            setCellData(sheetName, screenShotColName, i + index, message, url);
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public int getCellRowNum(String sheetName, String colName, String cellValue) {

    for (int i = 2; i <= getRowCount(sheetName); i++) {
        if (getCellData(sheetName, colName, i).equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Comment: What library is `Xls_reader` from?

Comment: Class file of reading writing the data in excel. @Thomas Timbul

Comment: That's a lot of code, but presumably the interesting part is `public boolean setCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String data)` - have you manually verified (with a debugger) that it correctly finds the correct column index?

Comment: Maybe you should isolate some of that code into easily testable chunks, such as `int findColumnIndexForName(String columnName)` find it once for each column outside your loop, then pass the index instead.

Comment: None of this code references Selenium or pom.xml. Please only put tags on questions that are directly relevant to the code posted, not what all is in your project. You need to add a tag for the Excel library that you are using.